# Permission denied error after entering right password on ssh

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi2, permission-denied

I am trying to access to a server through ssh.

I can connect from my laptop successfully.

But when I try to connect from raspberry pi, although I enter the right password, I get "permission denied" error. How can I solve the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: what is the error in server log? Are you connecting to same user (how?)?

Comment: How can I see the error on server log? Yes, I am connecting to the same user.

Comment: post the commands you are using to connect to the server. Post the log (with `-vvv` switches) from `pi` with the failure. Server log is in `/var/log/` which file depends on the distribution, but I believe you can make this up on your own.

Comment: Given that you have a case that works and one that doesn't, you are going to win this. In /etc/ssh/sshd_config, you can set LogLevel to DEBUG3 and restart sshd, then run the successful experiment and the failing one and compare the two sections of the log file to see what the difference is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post the commands you are using to connect to the server. Post the log (with -vvv switches) from pi with the failure. Server log is in `/var/log/`. Which file depends on the distribution.

I suspect you are connecting to your server as

```
ssh host
```

which is using the default user (same as your local machine, but not on the pi). You should always connect as

```
ssh user@host
```

if you don't have specified user in your `~/.ssh/config`. I might be wrong, but the logs will tell you the real reason.